Pydantic 2: "Input should be a valid list"
I'm using pydantic 2.5.1 with fastapi 0.103.2 and I got "Input should be a valid list" when trying to validate input using pydantic and dependency injection
I tried this python code:
class UserInput(BaseModel):
    role_id: str
    uids: list[str]

    @validator('role_id')
    def validate_role_id_length(cls, v):
        if len(v) != 16:
            raise ValueError("role_id must be 16 characters long")
        return v

    @validator('uids')
    def validate_uid_length(cls, v):
        for uid in v:
            if len(uid) != 16:
                raise ValueError("uids must be a list of 16 character strings")
        return v

@approuter.post("/role/add_user/{role_id}")
async def handle_user_ids(data: UserInput = Depends()):
    try:
        return {"message": f"Successfully processed user IDs for role {data.role_id}"}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

with this JSON payload:
{
  "uids": [
    "asdfasdfasdfasdf",
    "qwerqwerqwerqwer"
  ]
}

Give me "Input should be a valid list" error.
When I add another list like this:
class UserInput(BaseModel):
    role_id: str
    uids: list[str]
    asdf: list[str]

and add corresponding "asdf" list on json payload, it works properly

As I understand, FastAPI doesn't officially support this way of using Pydantic models (data: UserInput = Depends()).
Supporting Pydantic models for non-Body parameters is in the FastAPI roadmap (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/10370) and it's not implemented yet:

Support for Pydantic models for Query(), Form(), etc.

Don't mix Body parameters with anything else and don't use Depends(). This way everything works as expected:
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Path

app = FastAPI()

class UserInput(BaseModel):
    uids: list[str]
    
    @validator('uids')
    def validate_uid_length(cls, v):
        for uid in v:
            if len(uid) != 16:
                raise ValueError("uids must be a list of 16 character strings")
        return v

@app.post("/role/add_user/{role_id}")
async def handle_user_ids(data: UserInput, role_id: str = Path(min_length=16, max_length=16)):
    try:
        return {"message": f"Successfully processed user IDs for role {role_id}"}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

